# How to select a CSS class with jQuery, after it is changed

Tags: jquery

I have a button `Edit`, which on click it changes the class of all buttons from `btn` to `btnDel`.

So, after the `Edit` click I was expecting that the `$('.btnDel').on('click', function() {...}` will be triggered.

However the `$('.btn').on('click', function() {...}` is still triggered.

What am I missing?

```js
$('.btnEdit').on('click', function() {
  console.log("btnEdit was clicked");
  $(".btn").removeClass("btn").addClass("btnDel");
});

$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  console.log("btn was clicked");
});

$('.btnDel').on('click', function() {
  console.log("btnDel was clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btnEdit">Edit</button>
<br/><br/>
<button class="btn">1</button>
<button class="btn">2</button>
<button class="btn">3</button>
```

Comment: It changes it by reference so it will still trigger. You would need to instead bind the button after its changed..(also remember to unbind it to prevent memory leak)

Comment: Though a better solution is not to change its class change and instead have a higher up bubble capture for the click and detect the class, or have an if condition in the callback to detect it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is caused because you bind the event handler on page load not when you press the button. On page load there are no btnDel buttons so the handler is not bound to any element. To solve it you could use [event delegation](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

```js
$('.btnEdit').on('click', function() {
  console.log("btnEdit was clicked");
  $(".btn").removeClass("btn").addClass("btnDel");
});

$('#delegator').on('click', '.btn', function() {
  console.log("btn was clicked");
});

$('#delegator').on('click', '.btnDel', function() {
  console.log("btnDel was clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btnEdit">Edit</button>
<br/><br/>
<div id=delegator>
  <button class="btn">1</button>
  <button class="btn">2</button>
  <button class="btn">3</button>
</div>
```